# near TRANSACTION syntax error code 1 while compiling insert into

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im trying to put my transaction to the table using SQLite, but somehow i cant get it working, its always error, i already check the syntax but idk which one cause the error. Here is the source code.

```
public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "ifa.db";
    private static final int DB_VER=1;
    public Database(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME,null,DB_VER);
    }

    public void addToTransaction(Transaction transaction)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO TRANSACTION(date,companyname,itemname,itemtotal,itemprice,grandtotal,itemleft) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
                transaction.getDate(),
                transaction.getCompanyname(),
                transaction.getItemname(),
                transaction.getItemtotal(),
                transaction.getItemprice(),
                transaction.getGrandtotal(),
                transaction.getItemleft());
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
}
```

and this is the report i got

```
Process: com.example.crz.ifa, PID: 11831
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TRANSACTION": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO TRANSACTION(date,companyname,itemname,itemtotal,itemprice,grandtotal,itemleft) VALUES('14-11-2018','test','pen','2','5000','10000','50');
```

Comment: TRANSACTION is a SQL keyword. Use something else for your table name.

Comment: Also, learn how to use placeholders and how to bind values to them, instead of inserting random strings directly in a statement like that. [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) will thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Shawn, i will learn it for sure.

Comment: @Shawn maybe you can copy your comment to answer so i can flag it for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because **TRANSACTION** is a keyword and cannot be used as a name of a table column (and other items) unless it is enclosed/quoted.

Assuming that a table named TRANSACTION has been created (it would have to have been enclosed/quoted when defining it) then you could use one of the following :-

```
INSERT INTO `TRANSACTION`(date,co......
INSERT INTO 'TRANSACTION'(date,co......
INSERT INTO [TRANSACTION](date,co......
INSERT INTO "TRANSACTION"(date,co......
```

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Alternately the table itself could be renamed (this would probably be the better solution).